# Can a .NET 3.5 application run on Windows XP Home?

Tags: c#, .net

I have built an application in .NET framework 3.5, in C#.
I want to know whether it will run on a machine having Windows XP Home Basic
Service pack 3.

Thank You,
Bibhu

Comment: Just FYI, there is no XP Home Basic, just XP Home. Home Basic and Home Premium only exist since Vista.

Comment: @Michael Stum Good point, I edited the question so that it is more useful to visitors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say about your specific application (as it may have specific OS requirements depending on how you made it), but for .NET 3.5 applications in general, yes, they will run just fine.

Compatibility Matrix:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You must install the [.NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=333325fd-ae52-4e35-b531-508d977d32a6&displaylang=en) on your [Windows XP Home](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP#Editions) machine.

This will allow you to run standard applications built in C# or .NET in general.

However, you will not be able to serve web applications from the operating system using IIS, because IIS is not supported by XP Home.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this many times mostly on my clients who owns internet shops and all I did was install .net framework on each computers and then install the application. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Install .NET Framework 3.5 on the machine you intend to use for running your .net application, then your application will run.